# Waiting on asyncio futures outside asyncio.run()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I came across this pattern in some code base and it's breaking my mental model of how things work in asyncio. We have this function that awaits on a subset of futures and returns another subset that takes much longer to finish. It then waits for the second subset outside `asyncio.run()`. I'm not sure I understand where these second set of futures get CPU time given that there's no event loop outside asyncio.run(). Is it when we get to `f.result()` that they get a chance to run/finish?

```py
async def foo():

  futures_a = ...
  futures_b = ...

  await asyncio.gather(*futures_a)

  return futures b

async def main():

  tasks = set()

  tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(foo))
  tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(foo))
  tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(foo))

  return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


pending_futures = asyncio.run(main())

for f in pending_futures():
  f.result()
```

Comment: "It then waits for the second subset outside asyncio.run": It does not. It waits for all the tasks in `async def main()`; that's what the `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` is doing. Outside of `asyncio.run` it is simply looking at the result of tasks that have already completed.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. There's a bool argument for `foo()` that makes it await both subsets and I can see that with that option the asyncio.run() line would take much longer.

Comment: you can see the actual code [here](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/1831b3cd950b592c85422f7ace1b7e97eb621206/jax/experimental/array_serialization/serialization.py#L500)

Comment: ^ follow `commit_futures`

Comment: I fail to see what that code you linked has to do with your question.

Comment: `commit_futures` list is populated by some asyncio task and is then kept after asynio.run() has finished. The tasks await on a different set of futures. They then spawn a new thread in which they wait for these futures to complete. This seems to work but I'm not sure how/why.

Comment: Can you please just provide a coherent [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showcasing the behavior that confuses you? Your code above is not that. It should not be to difficult to make it actually workable. Until then, I am voting to close this.

Comment: sure I'll try to create a small example. My guess is that these futures are not vanilla asyncio futures. See https://google.github.io/tensorstore/python/api/tensorstore.Future.result.html

I'm assuming normal asyncio f.result() is non-blocking? These seem to be doing something a bit different

Comment: No, @larsks you are mistaken. At least with the code shown here (we need to guess a bit because it is incomplete and incorrect as is). Notice that `foo` returns some iterable of **coroutines** `futures_b`. In `main` the three `foo` tasks are awaited, but they themselves each return those `futures_b` coroutines. That means the output of that `gather` is a list of those iterables of coroutines. And they are never awaited anywhere in this code. I am still not sure what exactly is _supposed_ to be happening here. But those `futures_b` are never awaited.

Comment: You may be right! I should actually run the code first :).

Comment: Well it is difficult in this case because it is unclear (at least to me) what the _intent_ here is. I am curious to see a working demo though.

Comment: Nevermind, I just followed the link you posted, @Milad. It seems very clear from the context that your guess is correct. Those are not `asyncio.Future`s. See [here](https://google.github.io/tensorstore/python/api/tensorstore.Future.html). They have their own implementation. `.result` which **blocks the current thread** until the result is retrieved. This is the opposite of [`Future.result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.result), which will raise an error, if the result is not yet available. There is your answer.